# Laravel . Cron vs Queue

Tags: laravel, cron, queue

Hello fellow programmers. I google it before posting! Still confused about .
So here is the idea.
Users are planning post to be posted on their social media (concrete time ).
They can change post time even 2 minutes before . **Cron** would work as expected if it run every minute ,but it seems old solution. On the other hand **queue** works different (as far as I get) , trying to make better performance which means if there are high number of requests it will not post !!
Is there anything I am missing???
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefere old and reliable concepts over new and unreliable one.

About cron - I did set it to run regularry user script (under the user account) and then user can modify that script how often he wants and cron runs it regularry without need for reloading configuration. And the user script can do anything user can - so it can check if time is larger than some value and some unsent messages are pending and eventually send everything needed. So even if it fails send on scheduled time (maybe server down or anything else), it would be send next time the cron hits (maybe every minute)

Comment: Thanks for quick resposne. So concept I am trying to understand is .
Does queue does the same as cron or not .

Comment: no it doesn't do the same, laravel has a scheduler, so you run a cron ever minute but then in your schedule you can schedule different tasks to run at different times see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

As a side note, why not just update the time the post is supposed to hit once they hit save.